# Print caron using biber

Tags: bibtex, luatex, biber, characters

I am trying to cite a paper with the following authors:

```
author={Flaj{\v{\s}}manov{\'a}, Jana and {\v{S}}iler, Martin
  and Jedli{\v{c}}ka, Petr and Hrub{\`y}, Franti{\v{s}}ek
  and Brzobohat{\`y}, Oto and Filip, Radim and Zem{\'a}nek, Pavel},
```

However the letters with the caron and the `` {\`y} `` are simply not printed, other accents like `{\'a}` work.

I have

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal latex document so we can see what you are doing, and a full bibtex data entry that has a caron (this might for example also be an issue with your font).

Comment: Note that you should probably replace the `bibtex` tag by `biblatex` if you are using `biber`

Comment: What is `\s` in `{\v{\s}}`?

Comment: Why don't you type it directly on your keyboard?

Comment: Is ``\`y`` correct anyway? Czech doesn't use grave accents.

Comment: Googling (https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-020-70908-z) suggest `Brzobohat{\`y}, Oto` should be `Brzobohatý, Oto` and `Hrub{\`y}, Franti{\v{s}}ek` should be `Hrubý, František`. `Flaj{\v{\s}}manov{\'a}, Jana` is also wrong (`\s` is not defined) and should be `Flajšmanová, Jana`. So you never want `\\`y` anyway. With Biber it is usually preferable to use Unicode directly instead of the ASCII-macro escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry problem is solved. I was using lualatex along with fontenc and inputenc. Switching to fontspec solved the issue. Thanks for your help.